# sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION is not working on tablets

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I am making an app which is showing compass and I am trying to move compass as when the user rotates his device. For thi I am getting my sensor refrence in this way

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

this thing is working on hand held devices including lollipop version but when I run it on tablet 10' it  works. which is android jelly beans , but when I run it on 7' tablet with lollipop its wont run .

So please tell me what is problem. ? is it due to android version ? if so then Why it work on the handheld device which is also a Lollipop. Any guess or  idea about it??

Comment: TYPE_ORIENTATION was depreciated and it is up to the device manufacturer to implement it or not.

Comment: what do you mean by it up to manufacturer to implement it or not ?

Comment: You should check if the device has TYPE_ORIENTATION, if it does not that means that the manufacturer does not implement it.